# How to align two columns and adjacent cells corresponding to it in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, xlsx, xls

I have a data which contains multiple columns but i want to sync the data with another sheet and sync with entire columns as well.

Sheet 1:

```
 ID           Date
Vinod       2017-01-09
raj         2018-09-09
na          2018-09-09
pare        2019-08-06
jun         2020-09-08
```

Sheet 2 :

```
ID            Name         Data       Segment

Vinod        VINOD K      cddvfv      dfdvfd
ggggg        RAJAA K      cfdvfvf     cdfrgt
jun          DSDD K       ujhkjh      gbb
nane         edefeff      ojihjii     frgtgt
uiui         ddfdv        pojojn      vfgttk
raj          dvfvf        dff         cdfrgf
pare         dfcdf        fddfr       ffgrg
```

Expected O/P:

```
ID             Date       NAME      Data        Segment

Vinod       2017-01-09   VINOD K   cddvfv       dfdfd
raj         2018-09-09   dvfvf      dff         cdfrgf
na          2018-09-09
pare        2019-08-06   dfcdf      fddfr       ffgrg
jun         2020-09-08   DSDD K     ujhkjh      gbb
```

In the above two sheets the ID columns contains similar names and need to align with other columns as well from excel. I am trying with vlookup and other functions still i don't get any update. Can someone please help on it ?

Comment: If in `Sheet2` IDs are unique then `Vlookup()` will work fine otherwise you will always get first matching only.

Comment: If you are interested, this can be done pretty easily using `Power Query`, with a LeftOuter nested join. (But would not be dynamic as would be formulas -- you would have to refresh the query after changing data).

Answer (score 0):

Sheet1.C2 Pull right down

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!$A:$D,COLUMN(B1),)
```

Uploading attachments will solve the problem more accurately.

Answer (score 0):

Use `INDEX()/MATCH()` combination. Use `IFERROR()` to wrap error. After putting formula drag down and across as needed.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($E$2:$G$8,MATCH($B12,$D$2:$D$8,0),COLUMN(A1)),"")
```

[image]